# How does wikipedia turn key words into links?

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, wiki, wikipedia

I'm trying to code something in Node.js where I have a model called "tags". Say I want to see whenever a user types a tag in a comment, and turn that into a link to the relevant tag page.

For example, a user enters a comment: "What is a chicken?", and "chicken" turns into a link to the "chicken" tag page.

My current approach is to parse the text against database queries to the tag model, but this seems like a bad way, not to mention dealing multiple word tags like "chicken soup" etc...

Thanks so much for the help! I imagine wikipedia's got a good way of doing this.

Comment: No, Wikipedia doesn't have any automated way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not a bad idea. I have built many apps that do exactly that. Typically I use Redis or Memcache to build my search lists and I wait until I see a "space" before I query. In another app I wanted it to be more sensitive so we set it to space or over three characters to make my query.

If you support multiple words as a tag, which is equally common as single word only tags, then same rule applies but don't initiate the tag until the user clicks enter or on the tag.

Play with tags on Stackexchange and you can see the common UX behavior that you would expect. These are queried on the fly...

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I'm worried about the case where I have say two tags "chicken" and "chicken soup", but the latter never gets linked in a comment since "chicken" is always found first. Is there a good way of handling that?

Comment: (The user is not offered a list of tags to select from - it's for internal linking. Thanks!)

Comment: It actually does provide a valid and useful response, the poster even thanked me for the answer. The answer is the story for the business logic and a design to handle performance.

Answer (score 0):

On Wikipedia, all the links are added manually by editors. So while answering your question, I am sorry it will not help you further. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Linking for English Wikipedia help about links and https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Links for more details for links in MediaWiki in general.